# How can I use Transaction in FILE OPERATIONS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, transactions

My program needs to treat some file operations as a unit, some of the important steps in a case are:

1. delete a file in a directory.
2. validate some data. if the data is invalid, **roll back**.
3. Upload a file to the directory. if upload *failed* , **roll back**.
4. commit changes.

I raise this requirement about transaction is because sometimes a user may use VPN to access my website, the VPN connection maybe very unstable.

**If the 3rd step faild, the 1st file and the new uploaded file will all LOST.**

some of my code:

```
        DeleteTheOlderDT(path, FileName);

        this.fuTemplateName.SaveAs(path + FileName);
        _t.FileName = FileName;

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path + FileName))
        {
            ArrayList ItemList = new ArrayList();
            ItemList.Add("Uploading failed, please upload again!");
            btlError.DataSource = ItemList;
            btlError.DataBind();
            _t.FileName = "";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I know I can let the user to upload the file again. But the best way in my case is use transaction like we always do in ado.net.

Comment: I'd rethink the flow of operations to prevent headaches: first of all upload the file in a temporary location, if the upload succeeds validate some data, if the data validates perform the delete & move the uploaded file to the right location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a transaction to cover Moving a file and Inserting record in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939339/how-to-write-a-transaction-to-cover-moving-a-file-and-inserting-record-in-databa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only do this manually. Look at [UnitOfWork](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) from Martin Fowler, you can realize something like he described

Also check this links maybe the help you

- [transactional-file-manager](http://www.chinhdo.com/20080825/transactional-file-manager/)
- [STM.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee334183.aspx)
- [Article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx)

Comment: I think there's a way to solve this problem, cause this concept is very important. And database system is based on file system too. There should be a open-src framework or something.

Comment: Check links, which I added to my answer

Comment: THX, I also found that windows Vista/7, server2008 Natively support file transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it for File system but there is nice article available on code project.

Please take a look http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31270/A-Transactional-Repository-Implementation-in-NET

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista and newer support [Transactional NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS), which might help you out.

But really, you should consider reworking your logic - upload to a temporary file, and only delete the original file (and rename tempfile) if the upload succeeds.

Comment: that's a good idea, but there're many other place needs do that too, so  it's nessary to use a transaction, to make the code clearly.

Comment: ...then there's many other places where the code needs to be fixed ;-)