# Atomic transaction for both file system and DB operations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, transactions, io

I have a problem of implementing an atomic transaction that involves:

1. File system operations like add, edit, move, copy and delete
   files.
2. Linq operations (Entity Framework) like add object and
   save changes.

These two types of operations should be committed\Rolled back together.

I looked around for a solution and found out that (Transactional NTFS & The .NET `TransactionScope` class) is my best choice, now my question is does `TransactionScope` class supports EF linq operations? if you can provide me with simple examples I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a transaction to cover Moving a file and Inserting record in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939339/how-to-write-a-transaction-to-cover-moving-a-file-and-inserting-record-in-databa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Linq to Sql supports .Net Transactions.SaveChanges applies Transaction with Isolation level ReadCommitted. If you do have to apply More than one SaveChanges within one Transaction then you explicitly apply Transactions. EF SaveChanges  first checks whether there is already transaction it continues with it if not then It applies its own Transaction.If there is only one SaveChanges per transaction then there is no need to apply Transaction .

Comment: So when I start my scope with using transactionScope, EF saveChanges will continue with it and wont apply its own transaction, right?

Comment: and that also goes for AddObject?

Comment: Yes when you will apply your own transaction EF will goes with it.