# How to achieve transaction-like behavior for non-database operations?

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

Suppose I have a database table with a list of file paths/URLs of the form `<fileID><location>`, e.g.:

```
fileID  location
----------------------------------
0       C:\Folder\Sub\file1.txt
1       \\path\Folder\file2.txt
2       ftp://someftp/file3.txt
...
```

This table represents a list of files that should be deleted. What I want to do is:

1. delete a specific file located at "location";
2. `DELETE` the file record from the above table.

Like this:

```
MyClass.DeleteFile(fileId);             // statement 1
DELETE FROM table WHERE fileId=@fileId  // statement 2
```

**Problem:** If `DeleteFile()` succeeds but `DELETE` query fails, I want to un-delete the just-deleted file. What is the best way to ensure that either **both statements succeed, or none of them**? I.e. I want to have them in a transaction, but obviously this is not a *database* transaction.

- Note that `DeleteFile()` is backed up by different implementations depending on
  file location (e.g. filesystem vs ftp), so it's not simply
  e.g. a `File.Delete()` that is used for deleting.
- Is this something that must be solved *ad hoc* (I'd rather not implement my own full blown transactionality) or is there something that is as simple to use as `TransactionScope` is for database queries?

Comment: Command Pattern with Undo functionality? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755/design-pattern-for-undo-engine)

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939339/how-to-write-a-transaction-to-cover-moving-a-file-and-inserting-record-in-databa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (switch the order of the delete from DB and file deletion so that the file is deleted only after a successful DB transaction):

```
using (IDbTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {

        ...Delete File From DB Code...  // statement 2
        MyClass.DeleteFile(fileId);             // statement 1

        tran.Commit();
    }  catch {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```