# So TransactionScope is only used when dealing with database

Tags: c#

I was testing by making a file copy within the scope and then throwing and error, thinking it would revert the rename. It didn't revert :(

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Transactions;

namespace TestingTransactionScope
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    File.Move(@"C:\file1.txt", @"C:\file1.txt.backup1");
                    // Do Operation 1
                    // Do Operation 2
                    //...
                    MyClass.ThrowError();
                    // if all the coperations complete successfully, this would be called and commit the trabsaction. 
                    // In case of an exception, it wont be called and transaction is rolled back
                    scope.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }

        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public static void ThrowError()
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct.  Transactions are generally a database thing, though also extend to similar mediums such as message queues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions  I'm not aware of any file system that supports transactions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a transaction to cover Moving a file and Inserting record in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939339/how-to-write-a-transaction-to-cover-moving-a-file-and-inserting-record-in-databa)

Comment: What, in particular, in the documentation made you think TransactionScope was applicable to the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> The `System.Transactions` infrastructure makes transactional
>   programming simple and efficient throughout the platform by supporting
>   transactions initiated in **SQL Server, ADO.NET, MSMQ, and the
>   Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC).**

So, you can't use `System.Transactions` with the file system.

There is [Transactional NTFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/about-transactional-ntfs) component but Microsoft strongly recommends developers utilize alternative means to achieve your applications needs.

Also you can look at [TransactionalFileMgr](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=transactionalfilemgr)

Or [as said @ken2k,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7939517/4275342) you need to implement `IEnlistmentNotification` and allow manual standard file operations to work with `TransactionScope`. For instance, to enable rollback for a write operation on an existing file, it first creates a backup of the file that will be written, then writes to the backuped file, and finally replaces the initial file with the backuped/modified file if the transaction is committed, or deletes the backup file if the transaction is rollbacked

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good information already in the thread and they are correct; especially @Roman Marusyk. I thought what the heck and throw up a little example utilizing the `System.Transactions` and `Runtime.InteropServices` namespaces. The main function is `MoveFileTransactedW`, you can find more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefiletransactedw)

Note: You can rename the namespace, was for testing.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Transactions;

namespace MoveFileRollback
{
    public abstract class FileTransactionHelper
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool MoveFileTransactedW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string existingfile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string newfile,
            IntPtr progress, IntPtr lpData, IntPtr flags, IntPtr transaction);

        [ComImport]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        [Guid("79427A2B-F895-40e0-BE79-B57DC82ED231")]
        private interface IKernelTransaction
        {
            void GetHandle([Out] out IntPtr handle);
        }

        public static bool MoveFile(string existingFile, string newFile)
        {
            bool success = true;
            using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope())
            {
                if (Transaction.Current != null)
                {
                    IKernelTransaction kt = (IKernelTransaction)TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction.Current);
                    IntPtr txh;
                    kt.GetHandle(out txh);

                    if (txh == IntPtr.Zero) { success = false; return success; }

                    success = MoveFileTransactedW(existingFile, newFile, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, txh);

                    if (success)
                    {
                        tx.Complete();
                    }
                    CloseHandle(txh);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Move(existingFile, newFile);
                        return success;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { success = false; }
                }

                return success;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Quick Implementation**

```
if (FileTransactionHelper.MoveFile(@"C:\file1.txt", @"C:\file1.txt.backup1")){
                MessageBox.Show("MOVED");
            }
```

I tested this on a few different files, including throwing a exception in `MoveFile`, when it's thrown, the transaction doesn't get marked as `Complete` and the move doesn't happen.

If you have questions, please let me know, I hope this may be a little useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the file system doesn't support transactions. You can then delete the copied files in the catch block.