# Atomicity: Implementing a Resource Manager

Tags: c#, transactions, filesystems, atomic

I am trying to make sense of the following documentation:

- [Implementing a Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-a-resource-manager)

I find the documentation hard to read and understand, in particular it gives a false sense of support for transactions at application level. Let's consider the following SO reference, where poster requested support for `File.Move` within a transaction:

- [How to write a transaction to cover Moving a file and Inserting record in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939339/how-to-write-a-transaction-to-cover-moving-a-file-and-inserting-record-in-databa)

As of today, the accepted answer is (truncated):

```
TxFileManager fileMgr = new TxFileManager();
using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
    fileMgr.Copy(srcFileName, destFileName);

    scope1.Complete();
}
```

The first thing that stands out is that the accepted answer slightly modified the original poster request, in that answer changed line:

```
fileMgr.Move(srcFileName, destFileName);
```

into:

```
fileMgr.Copy(srcFileName, destFileName);
```

The important point being that the underlying system (the actual filesystem) may not provide an atomic `File.Move` operation (eg. obviously when crossing file system boundary).

How should I read the above documentation to understand what are the actual requirements when implementing a Resource Manager ? In particular, is it possible to implement a Resource Manager when the underlying system does not offer a **true** atomic operation (we can take the example of the `File.Move` operation accross file system boundaries as an example) ?

Comment: Of course you can implement a RM w/o any underlying transactional file system. That's exactly what most database systems such as SQL Server do, they don't rely on anything else but their code. But that doesn't mean it's a simple work to achieve yourself. On Windows, the most simple way is to reuse the DTC infrastructure with Compensating Resource Manager: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/com--compensating-resource-manager-concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i think you should make your resource manager durable:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.enlistdurable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads

Then you can save your file moving operation to a durable storage (file, database table,..) in the `Prepare` method (phase 1 of 2-phase commit protocol) with some format like `(Operation:FileMove, SrcFile, DesFile)`, this also helps with recovery later if the process crashes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.preparingenlistment?view=net-5.0 .

```
public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prepare notification received");

        //Validate if the File.Move is valid if it's executed later, then save your file moving operation to a temporary durable storage

        //If work finished correctly, reply prepared
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();

        // otherwise, do a ForceRollback
        preparingEnlistment.ForceRollback();
    }
```

In phase 2 (`Commit`), you can load the operation from the durable storage to actually move the file (use **retry** to ensure `true` atomic operation)

```
 public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Commit notification received");

        //Read to file moving operation from phase 1 to move the file and retry if the failure is transient

        //Declare done on the enlistment when the files have been moved 
        enlistment.Done();
    }
```

The point of saving the file moving operation in phase 1 is to ensure that:

- If any failure occurs in the `Commit` phase (due to `File.Move` operation accross file system boundaries) => `enlistment.Done()` is **not** called so the `Commit` method can be executed later, we still have the information in phase 1 to retry.
- Because our resource manager is durable, if the process crashes while in `Commit` method, in the recovery process we can retry the file moving operation thanks to the information persisted in `Prepare` phase